# JPA Many-to-Many relation: object(s) not refreshed

Tags: java, jpa

I have a very strange JPA-problem and hope to get some hints how to fix the problem.
I use newest Payara Full server with Eclipselink and the newest PostgreSQL-database.

I have a simple bidirectional "Many-to-Many" relationship. In an EJB-transaction, I create the company-object, persist it (entityManager.persist()), create the employee and set the company-object and persist(), then add the employee to the collection in the company-object and call a entitymanager.merge()... all within a single transaction (Stateless-EJB-public method).
=> the relationship is modeled after Vlads hints (use Sets instead Lists and so on...).

Now, in another transaction, I change the employee, merge() the changes and the changes are updated in the database. So from a point of view of the database, everything is fine (even the @Version field is updated accordingly).

But now, if I delete the company, it is removed successfully from the database, but in memory, the company is still there. And it gets more strange: Even if I call a refresh on the employee, the company is still referenced in the object, even if it is not existent in the database anymore.

If I mark company and employee as @Cachable(value=false), everything works fine. Even if I call entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll() instead of refreshing the employee, then it also removes the company from the empployee-object.

Is the problem perhaps in the inheritance-structure? I am very confused about the thing, that a call to entityManager.refresh(employee); does not fetch the fresh/current state from the database.

And it doesn't matter, if I change the owning-side of the relationship (already tested).

And equals()/hashCode are also implemented (without the collections, otherwise it will create circles), but the simple properties are mentioned, so that the changes in the other transaction
should/could be recognized.

So, can someone can give me some hints, where to look for the error? Dactivating Cache or evicting the cache is more a "hack" than a solution ;-).

Thank you very much in advance...

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistEntity implements Serializable {

    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ID = "_id";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "_id", length = 60)
    @Convert(converter = ObjectIdAttributeConverter.class)
    private ObjectId id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;

    // more simple properties

}


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistentExtEntity extends PersistentEntity {

    // only simple string properties

}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BusElementEntity extends PersistentExternalEntity {

    // only simple string properties

}


@Entity
public class Company extends BusinessElementEntity {

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH},  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Employee leader;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REFRESH
    }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_company",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comp_id")
    )
    private Set<User> employees = new HashSet<>();

    // ...

}


@Entity
public class Employee extends PersistentExtEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "emplyoees", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Company> companies = new HashSet<>();

    // ...

}


@Stateless
public class CompanyRepository {

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void createWithLeader(CreateCompanyRerquest request) {
        Employee leader = employeeRepository.create(request); // creates the emplyoee object and calls "persist()"
        Company company = new Company(request);
        company.setLeader(emplyoee);
        company.addEmplyoee(company.getLeader());
        company.getLeader().getCompanies().add(company);
        company.prePersist(); // this is an known eclipse bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445272)
        entityManager.persist(company);
        entityManager.merge(company.getLeader());
    }


    public void deleteCompany(String externalCompanyId) {
        final Optional<Company> companyOptional = getByExternalId(externalCompanyId);
        Company dbCompany = companyOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new APIException(GlobalApiErrorCode.E4040001));
//        entityManager.refresh(dbCompany); // contains still the very old employee object
        dbCompany.getLeader().getCompanies().remove(dbCompany);
        entityManager.merge(dbCompany.getLeader());
        entityManager.remove(dbCompany);
}
```

Comment: *But now, if I delete the company, it is removed successfully from the database, but in memory, the company is still there* - how are you deleting?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that... have added the code above.